# call stored procedure in loopback4

Tags: loopback4

I want to call a stored procedure with parameters which is in MYSQL using loopback4. Do I need to add new controller and how to handle return type for that do I need to create a specific Model?

Answer (score 1):

You can call DataSource.execute() directly from a controller

```
@get('/sptest', {
  responses: {
    '200': {
      description: 'test for executing sp',
    },
  },
})
async sptest(): Promise<any> {
  return this.anyRepository.dataSource.execute('EXEC DBO.SP_SOMETHING param1, param2');
}
```